# Fire events when the button is ajax loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a form to send someone a message, and I need to create a list of people to the user pick one and send him the message.

So I've created a search field that shows that list:

```
$('#name').keyup(function(){
    var name, goURL;
    goURL = site_url + 'events/search';
    name = $(this).val();
    $.post(goURL, {name : name}).done(function(data){
        $('.results').html(data);
    });
});
```

Then I get a list from users, that comes from a method of codeigniter and in each user I have a button that allows me to pick this user.

```
    $('.results').on('on', '.select-btn', function(){
        alert('Test');
    });
```

But when I click, nothing happens. How to proceed?
Thank you and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: use click event instead of on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `click` event as event while binding using on:

```
$('.results').on('click', '.select-btn', function(){
    alert('Test');
});
```

Comment: oh, that's awkward, haha. Thank you!